# c# WebView2 ==> How to get selected text from WebView2 window

Tags: c#, webview2

How do I

> dynamic document = webView1.Document.DomDocument;
> dynamic selection = document.selection;
> string text = selection.createRange().text;
> return text;

works in webBrowser.

I need to highlight a text in the WebView browser and return it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2.executescriptasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.902.49#Microsoft_Web_WebView2_WinForms_WebView2_ExecuteScriptAsync_System_String_

Answer (score 0):

From your host code (C#) you can call [webView2.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.postwebmessageasjson?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.902.49) to pass an arbitrary JSON-encoded Javascript object to Javascript in your browser environment.

Maybe something like this would work to tell your browser Javascript to get text from your clipboard.

```cs
webView2.CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson(
       "\"verb\":\"getclipboard\",\"format\":\"text\"}")

webView2.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += MessageHandler;

private void MessageHandler 
          (object s, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs e) {
    var clipboardText = e.TryGetMessageAsString();
}
```

In your browser Javascript you can do

```js
window.chrome.webview.addEventListener('message',  function (event) {
    const payload = event.data
    if (payload.verb === 'getclipboard') {
      /* do what you need to do with your clipboard */
      const clipboardText = 'whatever'
      windows.chrome.webview.postMessage(clipboardText);
} )
```

That postMessage will deliver an event to your host MessageHandler.